# If-Modified-Since header not working

Tags: rest-api, describesobject, workbench

I am trying to use the If-Modified-Since header with SObject Describe
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/describe_global_with_ifmodified_header.htm

I want to know if the contact object's metadata has been modified since the specified date. I am using the Workbench REST Explorer.

My Request Header is

> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>   Accept: application/json
>   If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Jul 2017 00:00:00 GMT

and endpoint is

> /services/data/v39.0/sobjects/contact/describe

I have not made any changes to contact metadata but it is still returning metadata for contact instead of HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified status code.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling across this, I think I figured it out. It seems to be that the value used for the `If-Modified-Since` header is incorrect, i.e. even though the Contact object was not technically updated, Salesforce is returning a `Last-Modified` value in the response header when performing a GET to `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Contact/describe` which must then be used in further calls.

For example, in my DE org I have not made any updates on the Contact object, but the value being returned in the `Last-Modified` response header is `Fri, 13 May 2022 04:48:00 GMT` (the actual time of writing this answer is Fri, 13 May 2022 13:03:00 GMT).

So, specifying a value of anything greater than equal to that `Last-Modified` date will result in `HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified` as desired. But any date less than that `Last-Modified` will return `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and the describe payload.

The same is true for sobject describe too (`/services/data/v53.0/sobjects`). To use either of these services effectively in conjunction with the `If-Modified-Since` header, you must first retrieve the `Last-Modified` response header from an initial call, and then use that in conjunction with further calls (unless of course, there is a way of magically knowing the correct date/time).

Answer (score 1):

From Salesforce Documentation:

> If-Modified-Since:
>
> The If-Modified-Since header is a time-based request header. The
>   request is processed only if the data has changed since the date and
>   time specified in the header. Otherwise, a 304 Not Modified status
>   code is returned, and the request isn’t processed.

Here is the link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_conditional_requests.htm