# How to use SObject Describe resource and the If-Modified-Since HTTP Header in workbench

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest, workbench

I'm trying to use **If-Modified-Since** in workbench, based on the [example available in Rest API developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/sobject_describe_with_ifmodified_header.htm).
But I'm not able to see the desired response.

Here is what I tried so far:
[image]

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Looks right to me: if you specify say today's date/time you still get a 200 response?

Comment: based on documentation, they have mentioned that it will give HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 05:03:24 GMT in response, Even giving today's date/time I'm still getting 200

Comment: Yeah I agree and can't see what is wrong.

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper in case you're still interested, please see answer I just provided here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186494/if-modified-since-header-not-working